# Punctures in high dimensions.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, fundamental-groups

> Let $X$ be a path-connected Hausdorff space and $p\in X$ a point that has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^d$ for some $d\geq3$. Show that for any $x_0\in X\setminus\{p\}$, we have $\pi_1(X,x_0)\cong\pi_1(X\setminus\{p\},x_0).$

I have an idea to prove this statement, but it seems a bit too straightforward, so I’d like some checking.

For any loop $\gamma$ that passes through $p$ in $X$, if I can find a loop $\alpha$ that avoids $p$ and homotopic to $\gamma$, then I’m done. Let $U$ be the open neighborhood of $p$ that is homeormorphic to $\mathbb{R}^d$. Every time a portion of $\gamma$ enters $U$, we just replace it with a homotopic path that avoids $p$, which is possible in $\mathbb{R}^d$. $\alpha$ would then consists of the portions of $\gamma$ outside $U$ and those substituting sub-paths.

If this is indeed the idea, what’s the role of the Hausdorff property of the space?

Comment: Can you see the issue with the following argument: "Every path connected space $X$ is contractible: indeed for any $x \in X$ there is a path from $x$ to some point $*$. Since a map $X \times I \rightarrow X$ is equivalent to a collection of paths in $X$ indexed by $x \in X$, to demonstrate a space is contractible it suffices to give a collection of paths from each $x$ to $*$. Since by assumption $X$ is path connected, we always have such a collection of paths."

Comment: Why not just use Van Kampen?

Comment: @ConnorMalin When we defined contractible spaces in our class we used trivial fundamental group as a criterion, so I have to think a bit about the definition that you’ve given. But I will give it a go. Does the problem lie in the following scenario: we might have a hole in the space, and two paths connecting x to $\ast$ in such a way that together they “encompass” the hole, and hence we can’t get from one to another without having to “go through” the hole, i.e. having a discontinuity? But this only happens in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and not in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or higher dimensions?

Comment: @NickL we haven’t got to Van Kampen in our course yet.

Comment: Yes that is a good explanation of what goes wrong. The reason I put this out there is because you need to explain how you can do everything in your post continuously. If you can do this (which depends on the dimension), then I think the proof has the right idea.

Comment: By the way, your argument would only show that $\pi_1(X\setminus\{p\},x_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_0)$ is onto.